# How does NSMutableArray allocate memory while adding many objects?

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray

How does `NSMutableArray` keep adding new objects without any limit? Is it some concept of linked list behind the api? We can keep adding because it can allocate memory in runtime and link with last one. If not then how can we make dynamic size in array concept?

Comment: http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/03/05/exposing-nsmutablearray/